# Search form with a `belongs_many_many` to `has_one` relationship

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've got a relationship like so:

```
class Registration extends DataObject {

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        "Workshops" => "Workshop"
    );
}

class Workshop extends DataObject {

    private static $has_one = array(
        "Course" => "Course"
    );
}

class Course extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        "Title" => "Title"
    );
}
```

I'm using `ModelAdmin` for `Registration` and I want to customise the search form for Registrations for a particular course, ie a drop down (as long as less than 100) of the course title.

I've tried lots of different configs for example:

```
private static $searchable_fields = array(
    "Workshops.Course.Title"
);
```

or

```
private static $searchable_fields = array(
    "Workshops.CourseTitle"
);
```

However I get a different range of errors to do with `scaffoldSearchField`

How can I search on the relationship? The form will get more complex and I've tried looking into overriding the form but not sure how to do it.

Comment: After 5 hours trying things out I got it working. I'll post answer when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there may be a way to get this working automatically I had to implement a custom `getSearchContext` like so:

```
public function getSearchContext() {
    $context = parent::getSearchContext();

    $context->getFields()->push($dropdown = new DropdownField('WorkshopID', "Workshop", $workshops));
    $dropdown->setEmptyString('-- Select Course --');

    return $context;
}
```

And then apply the custom filter:

```
public function getList() {
    $list = parent::getList();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->requestVars();
    $list = $list->filter(array("Workshop.CourseID" => $params['WorkshopID']));

    return $list;
}
```

Both of these are in your class extending ModelAdmin